# Google cloud - nodejs with mongodb setup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to setup a nodeJS app environment with mongoDB cluster all deployed in Google cloud. I have created a mongoDB cluster as given in Google Cloud documentation. But after this I could not find any documentation on how to get that working with nodeJS environment.

Is there any documentation or tutorial for end to end Google Cloud setup?

Answer (score 0):

Try the "MEAN" stack from Bitnami from the [Cloud Launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/#/explore?q=mean): is a on-click-deploy solution for Mongo/Express/Angular/Node.

This is good to getting started, when you know how the stack works you can opt for docker images for Mongo and Node and deploy that on [Kubernetes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers) to get a fully-managed cluster env.